Django Rest Framework ManytoMany Feld Serializing
Models:
class MaterialAttribute(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a material attribute.

    Attributes:
        name (CharField): The name of the material attribute.
    """

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Material Attribute"
        verbose_name_plural = "Material Attributes"
        db_table = "material_attribute"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class MaterialType(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a material type.

    Attributes:
        name (CharField): The name of the material type.
        attributes (ManyToManyField): The attributes of the material type.
    """

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Material Type"
        verbose_name_plural = "Material Types"
        db_table = "material_type"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(
        MaterialAttribute, related_name="material_types"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

I want to write a MaterialTypeSerializer in that way, that for list/retrieave it returns the Json representation
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Format"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Farbe"
            }
        ]
    } 

of the Attrtibutes and for create/update
{
"name": "Test",
        "attributes": [
            {
                1
            },
            {
                2
            }
        ] 
}

the primary key.
class MaterialAttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the MaterialAttribute model.

    This serializer includes the following fields:
    - id: The unique identifier of the material attribute.
    - name: The name of the material attribute.

    All fields are read-only.
    It is used to serialize minimal material attribute data.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialAttribute
        fields = ["id", "name"]


class MaterialAttributeManyField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return MaterialAttributeSerializer(value).data

class MaterialTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the MaterialType model.

    This serializer includes the following fields:
    - id: The unique identifier of the material type.
    - name: The name of the material type.
    - attributes: The attributes associated with the material type.

    All fields are read-only.
    It is used to serialize minimal material type data.
    """

    attributes = MaterialAttributeManyField(
        queryset=MaterialAttribute.objects.all(), many=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialType
        fields = ["id", "name", "attributes"]


However, this results in a "unhashable type: 'ReturnDict'"
I try to not override the create and update mehtods of the serializer to keep the code simple.
If someone knows a clean way to solve this i woudl appreciate it

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Article, Tag


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ("id", "name")


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("id", "title", "tags")
        
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation["tags"] = TagSerializer(instance.tags.all(), many=True).data
        return representation

I think that example works actually the same way.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
